Is the Gita Saar (summary of Bhagavad Gita) an authentic scripture?
You will find so many hits if you type Gita Saar in Google. You will find it in English, Hindi, Bengali, and probably in other languages as well. There are 10-15 lines. As a sample, I attached this picture from the Batu Caves Temple.

It goes something like this - whatever happened, happened for good. Whatever is happening, is happening for good so on and so forth. It is quite popular.
I was wondering, whether Gitasaar is an authentic Hindu scripture. Bhagavad Gita itself is a summary of the Upanishads. It is said that if Upanishads can be compared to cows, then Gita is the milk. So, why do we need a summary of a summary? I am a bit sceptical.
Who wrote this so-called Gitasaar? How did it become so popular? Is it authentic?

You can check this site for some informations. I hope this helps. Prd..

@SriShivaCharañamDāsaVishñu thanks for this link. This misleading stuff needs to be busted and rejected.

You are most Welcome. ..
